# Python Find distance between two coordinates

Tags: python

I'm working with a range of 0 to 255.

My data would be a set of numbers within this range.

Except I need the difference between

```
255 & 0 = 1
254 & 5 = 7
```

So in a sense this range is a circular set, and 255 and 0 are the pole.

Is there some function / easy way to do this?  Or do I need to take the second half of the range and assign it some value to be calculated against?  i.e. 255 becomes 255 - 254 if it is being compared against [1 - 127.4]

Comment: Do you want your answer to always be positive?  And furthermore always the smaller of the two possibilities, i.e. 254-5 could be 7 OR 249 but you always want 7?

Comment: yes, always the smaller of the possibilities.  Also always positive.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
def diff256(a, b):
  return min((a - b) % 256, (b - a) % 256)
```

Comment: Nice.  Nailed it.  Nice and clean because the result of `%` always has the same sign as the second argument, which is `+256`.  Very nice.

Comment: Thank you both.  This is really interesting, and artful.

Comment: It can be done in one mathematical expression instead of two, `abs((abs(a - b) // 128) * 128 - (a - b) % 128)`, but using `min` is the right way to do it.